# Rails removes port from local environment variable?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, port, erb

I have a very strange problem with my rails 4.1.0 application.

Inside `local_env.yml` I have a variable declared as:

```
API_URL: 'http://api.myapp.com:3000'
```

I use this variable in the javascript file `app_ready.js.erb` like so:

```
var apiHost = '<%= ENV["API_URL"] %>'
```

But for some reason when I call the page using this script and inspect the `app_ready.js` file I can see the line got converted to `var apiHost = 'http://api.myapp.com'` without the port `:3000`. Does anybody know what is happening here?

**Edit:**

Is there some kind of a server sided cache maybe? Because at some point I might have declared `API_URL` without the port and changed it later. It can't be in the browser cache, because I've actually cleared it and even tried with different browsers with the same results.

Comment: How are you contacting it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'contacting it'?

Comment: I mean, how are you contacting the API using that address? Actual code, if possible.

Comment: I just do a common ajax request `$.ajax({ url: apiHost + "/locations", type: "GET", success: function(data){ ...`. I'm just not sure how this relates to the problem. What can be observed when I inspect the page and look at `app_ready.js` is that the line `var apiHost = '<%= ENV["API_URL"] %>'` got converted to `var apiHost = 'http://api.myapp.com'` where I would expect it to be `http://api.myapp.com:3000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was the cache. Had to run `rake tmp:clear` and restart rails server.

Comment: In fact none of the cace clearing commands I have tried so far seem to have any effects on heroku - the other one I tried was  `heroku run -a APP_NAME rails runner -e production Rails.cache.clear`. The environment variable on heroku is not set in a file but in the app settings - maybe the problem is somewhere in that area...